# Why doesn't the genNewColor function work?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This code is supposed to generate a random color. I'm not sure why it isn't working, I believe it has something to do with the function since the css formatting works great. When I run the code, I don't get any error messages, the code just simply doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
 Color Generator 
</title>
<style>
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #161818;
 font-family: "Consolas";
}
.color{
 margin-top: 300px;
 text-align: center;
}
#hex{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 100px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0px;
}
.color button{
 background: none;
 outline: 10px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 40px;
 border: 3px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="color">
  <span id="hex">#??????</span>
  <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate New Color</button>
  </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function genNewColor() {
  var symbols,color;
  symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  
  color = "#";
  for(var i =0;i<6;i++){
   color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color
 }
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing end `</script>` tag: (scroll down the preview window)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
 Color Generator 
</title>
<style>
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #161818;
 font-family: "Consolas";
}
.color{
 margin-top: 300px;
 text-align: center;
}
#hex{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 100px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0px;
}
.color button{
 background: none;
 outline: 10px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 40px;
 border: 3px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="color">
  <span id="hex">#??????</span>
  <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate New Color</button>
  </button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function genNewColor() {
  var symbols,color;
  symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  
  color = "#";
  for(var i =0;i<6;i++){
   color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color
 }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<button>` element has an extra `</button>` closing tag and your `<script>` tag is missing the `</script>` closing tag.

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a practical example of your code with above fixes:

```js
function genNewColor() {
  var symbols,color;
  symbols = "0123456789ABCDEF";

  color = "#";
  for(var i =0;i<6;i++){
    color = color + symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]
  }
  document.body.style.background = color;
  document.getElementById("hex").innerHTML = color
}
```

```css
body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 background: #161818;
 font-family: "Consolas";
}
.color{
 margin-top: 100px;
 text-align: center;
}
#hex{
 display: block;
 color: white;
 font-size: 100px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin: 0px;
}
.color button{
 background: none;
 outline: 10px;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-size: 40px;
 border: 3px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="color">
  <span id="hex">#??????</span>
  <button onclick="genNewColor()">Generate New Color</button>
</div>
```